# Unable to install python ldap module on windows

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

**Tried installing python-ldap, but failed**

```
    "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DHAVE_SASL -DHAVE_TLS -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DHAVE_LIBLDAP_R -DLDAPMODULE_VERSION=3.4.0 "-DLDAPMODULE_AUTHOR=python-ldap project" "-DLDAPMODULE_LICENSE=Python style" -IModules -IC:\Users\rathod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\include -IC:\Users\rathod\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\cppwinrt" /TcModules/LDAPObject.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-39\Release\Modules/LDAPObject.obj
      LDAPObject.c
      c:\users\rathod\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-dkw9jd4z\python-ldap_05f9ed21408d4097a9c6bd894511d8b7\modules\common.h(15): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'lber.h': No such file or directory
      error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.16.27023\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for python-ldap
Failed to build python-ldap
ERROR: Could not build wheels for python-ldap, which is required to install pyproject. toml-based projects
```

**Tried using few of the .whl files from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#_python-ldap](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#_python-ldap), but failed**

```
PS C:\Users\rathod\source\repos\00 Dell-Gitlab staging\replication_status> pip install .\python_ldap-3.4.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl
ERROR: python_ldap-3.4.0-cp311-cp311-win32.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.
```

**Has anyone faced same challenge, and if there is any way to install this old module on windows system?**

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: For my own projects that need to run on Windows, I use the pure-Python `ldap3` module instead – its API is not my favorite but easier to install on Win. (Actually ended up making an abstraction layer over 'ldap3' and 'ldap'.)

Comment: Thank you @user1686. I am planning to upgrade the code to use ldap3